# Use @Value when defining custom @Conditional

Tags: spring

I would like to create custom condition that will be pass as value to `@Conditional` interface applied on `@Configuration` class. Basically I would like to create beans from `Config1` or `Config2` depending on a configuration that is stored in a database - `dbConfig.get('configType')` connects to the database and returns the value. However it looks that `dbConfig` is not created at that time yet. What could be a way to resolve it? I would like to avoid `if-else` within a bean definition to differentiate creation code.

```
@Configuration
@Conditional(OnCondition1.class)
public class Config1{
// beans definitions
}

@Configuration
@Conditional(OnCondition2.class)
public class Config2{
// beans definitions
}

public class OnCondition1 implements Condition{
   @Value("#{dbConfig.get('configType')}")
   private String configType;

   @Override
    public boolean matches(ConditionContext conditionContext, AnnotatedTypeMetadata annotatedTypeMetadata) {
        return configType.equals('1');
    }
}

public class OnCondition2 implements Condition{
   @Value("#{dbConfig.get('configType')}")
   private String configType;

   @Override
    public boolean matches(ConditionContext conditionContext, AnnotatedTypeMetadata annotatedTypeMetadata) {
        return configType.equals('2');
    }
}
```

Comment: You cannot. As this runs very early in the process. What you can do is create a database driver `PropertySource` use an `EnvironmentPostProcessor` to add it and use a regular `ConditionalOnProperty` to enable certain beans.

Comment: Thank you, got it. I thought if @ Value content is available inside @ Bean method's code, I could use it. But I will try with your suggestion then.

Comment: The conditionals aren't beans but are created outside the context and are then used to configure said context.